# How to Retrieve Parse Objects from UITableView Cell and Present it in a Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a `UITableView` that contains a list of `PFObjects` (they are group names), when the user taps on one of the cells, I want all the object info from that specific selected object to be retrieved and presented in the detail view controller. I would appreciate any help!

```
class GroupNamesTable: UITableViewController{

    let cellidentifier = "Cell"

    var dataparse: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    func loaddata () {    
        var findgroups: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BeaterGroups")
        findgroups.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in    
            if error == nil && objects != nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.dataparse.addObject(object)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }        
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loaddata()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellDataParse.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("GroupInfoSegue", sender: self)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let currentcell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
        println(currentcell.textLabel!.text!)
        var query = PFQuery(className: "BeaterGroups")
        query.whereKey("GroupName", equalTo: currentcell.textLabel!.text!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println(objects)
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: \(error!)")
            }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call only the `performSegueWithIdentifier()` in  the tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and get the `BeaterGroups` object in the `prepareForSegue()` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("GroupInfoSegue", sender: self)
}
```

When getting the object, you don't need to query it again since you already have it in your `dataparse` array. Just use the indexPath of the selected cell and get the object out of the array:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "GroupInfoSegue") {
        // get indexPath of selected cell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        // get object from your dataparse array using the indexPath
        var groupObject = self.dataparse[indexPath!.row]

        println(groupObject.objectId)

        // pass the object to your destination view controller...
        ....
    }
}
```